# Is every connected scheme path connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, ac.commutative-algebra

Every (?) algebraic geometer knows that concepts like homotopy groups or singular homology groups are irrelevant for schemes *in their Zariski topology*. Yet, I am curious about the following.

Let's start small. Consider a local ring $A$ with maximal ideal $M$; is the affine scheme $X=Spec(A)$  connected? Sure, because every open subset of $X$ containing $M$ is equal to $X$ itself. Or because the only idempotents of $A$ are $0$ and $1$. But is it path connected? Yes, because if you take any point $P$ in $X$ the following path $\gamma$  joins it to $M$ (reminds you of the hare and the tortoise...):

$ \gamma(t)=P \quad  for \quad  0\leq t < 1\quad , \quad \gamma (1)=M $.

The same trick shows that the spectrum of an integral domain is path connected: join the generic point to any prime by a path like above. More generally, in the spectrum of an arbitrary ring $R$ you can join a prime $P$ to any bigger prime $Q$   $(P \subset Q)$ by adapting the formula above:

$ \gamma(t)=P \quad  for \quad  0\leq t < 1\quad , \quad \gamma (1)=Q $.

[Continuity at $t=1$ follows from the fact that every neighbourhood of $Q$ contains $P$ and so its  inverse image under $\gamma$ is all of $[0,1]$ ]

The question in the title just asks more generally:
**Is a connected scheme path connected ?**

**Edit** (after reading the comments) If an arbitrary topological space is connected and if every point has at least one path connected open neighbourhood, then the space is path connected. But I don't see why the local condition holds in a scheme, affine or not, even after taking into account what I proved about local rings.

Comment: Can't you just 'zigzag' around X with paths like the one you describe?

Comment: Yes if $X$ is noetherian, because your argument shows that $X$ is locally path-connected.

Comment: Martin, I don't see how my argument shows that *X* is locally path connected. If however local path connectedness holds ( or even less: cf. my Edit), then the answer to the question will indeed be "yes" (even without any noetherian hypothesis).

Comment: Local path-connectedness implies local connectedness, and the latter can fail for Spec(R) when R is not noetherian. I believe that in  Spec of an infinite product of fields every point is closed, only the obvious points are isolated, and there enough idempotents in the ring to show that the only connected sets are the points. (So each non-obvious point fails to have a connected nbhd.)

Comment: I wonder if there can be a (non-noetherian) ring R having exactly two maximal ideals, such that no prime ideal belongs to both of them, but such that Spec(R) is connected.

Comment: Perhaps you can construct a counterexample with an uncountable gluing construction, e.g., with $\mathbb{P}^1$s replacing intervals in the construction of the extended long line.

Comment: It is not hard to show every irreducible scheme is path connected. Indeed, map [0,1) to the generic pt, and {1} to any target pt in the scheme, then this will be a path connecting the generic pt and the target pt. Therefore if our scheme is locally Noetherian and locally connected, then it is true. Now we can further ask two questions: can a connected scheme be non locally connected? Can a connceted affine scheme (therefore no non trivial idempotents) have infinitely many irreducible components? If either fails, I would expect a negative answer.

Comment: There's an old paper of Hochster, "Prime ideal structure of commutative rings" which answers exactly what topological spaces come from Spec $R$ (for arbitrary commutative rings $R$).  This sounds like it may be relevant here.

Comment: @Ying Zhang & Karl: One of the most interesting applications in the referenced paper of Hochster (his thesis, actually) is that, for any (commutative) ring R, there is another ring R' such that the prime ideals of R and R' are in bijection, but with containment reversed. A nice example: R = k[x], for an algebraically closed field k. Then Spec R' has infinitely many irreducible components, but just one closed point (so it's connected).

Comment: Dear Dave, although I browsed Hochster' thesis some time ago (without checking the proofs: I found them quite technical), I didn't remember this most interesting fact. It might be an interesting source of (counter)examples: thanks for this useful addition to an algebraic geometer's toolbox.

Comment: Maybe another (trivial) comment is that if instead we look at mspec, which are just $T_1$ and quasi compact topological spaces by Hochster's thesis, then the topological sine curve when $x\in [-1,1]$ could be a connected but not path connected example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There exist connected affine schemes which are not path connected. Let E be a compact connected metric space* which is not path connected (e.g., the [closed topologist's sine curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve)) and consider the following.

> $X={\rm Spec}(A)$ where $A$ is the ring of continuous functions $f\colon E\to\mathbb{R}$.

Then X is connected, since any idempotent f satisfies $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$ and, by connectedness of E, $f=0$ or $f=1$. The maximal ideals of A are
$$
\mathcal{m}_x=\left\{f\in A\colon f(x)=0\right\}
$$
for $x\in E$. There will also non-maximal primes (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35793/prime-ideals-in-c0-1) for example) but, every prime ideal will be contained in one and only one of the maximal ideals**. So, we can define $\pi\colon X\to E$ by $\pi(\mathcal{p})=x$ for prime ideals $\mathcal{p}\subseteq\mathcal{m}_x$.

In fact, $\pi$ is continuous, using the following argument. For any open ball $B_r(x)$ in E, choose $f\in A$ to be positive on $B_r(x)$ and zero elsewhere. Then $D_f=\left\{\mathcal{p}\in X\colon f\not\in \mathcal{p}\right\}$ is open and $\pi^{-1}(B_r(x))\subseteq D_f\subseteq \pi^{-1}(\bar B_r(x))$.
Writing $B_r(x)=\cup_{s < r}B_s(x)=\cup_{s < r}\bar B_s(x)$, this shows that there are open sets $U_s$ lying between $\pi^{-1}(B_s(x))$ and $\pi^{-1}(\bar B_s(x))$. So, $\pi^{-1}(B_r(x))=\bigcup_{s < r} U_s$ is open, and $\pi$ is continuous.

So, $\pi\colon X\to E$ is continuous and onto. If X was path connected then E would be too.

It may be worth noting that ${\rm Specm}(A)$ is also connected but not path connected, being homeomorphic to E.

---

(*) I assume that E is a metric space in this argument so that the open balls give a basis for the topology, and there are continuous $f\colon E\to\mathbb{R}$ which are nonzero precisely on any given open ball. Actually, it is enough for the topology to be generated by the continuous real-valued functions. So the argument generalizes to any compact Hausdorff space (+ connected and not path connected, of course).

(**) Maybe I should give a proof of the fact that every prime $\mathcal{p}$ is contained in precisely one of the maximal ideals $\mathcal{m}_x$. Let $V(f)=\{x\in E\colon f(x)=0\}$ be the zero set of f. Then, $V(\mathcal{p})\equiv\bigcap\{V(f)\colon f\in\mathcal{p}\}$ will be non-empty. Otherwise, by compactness, there will be $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\in\mathcal{p}$ with $V(f_1)\cap V(f_2)\cap\cdots\cap V(f_n)=\emptyset$. Then, $f=f_1^2+f_2^2+\cdots+f_n^2\in\mathcal{p}$ would be nonzero everywhere, so a unit, contradicting the condition that $\mathcal{p}$ is a proper ideal. Choosing $x\in V(\mathcal{p})$ gives $\mathcal{p}\subseteq\mathcal{m}_x$.

On the other hand, we cannot have $\mathcal{p}\subseteq\mathcal{m}_x\cap\mathcal{m}_y$ for $x\not=y$. Letting $f,g\in X$ have disjoint supports with $f(x)\not=0, g(y)\not=0$ gives $fg=0\in\mathcal{p}$ and, as $\mathcal{p}$ is prime, $f\in\mathcal{p}\setminus\mathcal{m}_x$ or $g\in\mathcal{p}\setminus\mathcal{m}_y$.

Comment: "every prime ideal will be contained in one and only one of the maximal ideals" - how could this possibly be true? Take any connected closed subset $F$ of $E$ and the corresponding prime in $A$ will be contained in every maximal ideal $m_x$ where $x\in F.$ 

Comment: @Victor: the ideal corresponding to $F$ is not a prime unless $F$ is a point: the quotient is $\mathcal{C}(F,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Dear Anonymous, there is just one point that I don't understand: why do we have $D_f\subseteq \pi^{-1}(\bar B_r(x))$ ? Imagine a prime ideal $p \subsetneq m_z$ (strict inclusion) with $z\notin \bar B_r(x)$. Then $f\in m_z$ of course, but could it not happen that $f\notin p$, in which case we would have $p\in D_f$ but $\pi (p)=z \notin \bar B_r(x)$ ? 

Comment: Choose a $g\in A$ with $g(z)\not=0$ and support disjoint from $B_r(x)$. Then $fg=0\in p$ but $g\not\in m_z$. So $f\in p$.

Comment: Right, thank you. Dear Anonymous, I can't tell you how impressed I am by this brilliant answer : it is a real gem. I am sorry that I can't do more to show my gratitude and admiration than upvoting you and accepting your answer. Also, I wish you Godspeed in your projected change of career: you obviously more than deserve a position in Academia. 

Comment: Thanks for those kind words and encouragement. Regarding this answer, it is interesting to note that $X={\rm Spec}(A)$ deformation retracts onto ${\rm Specm}(A)$, which is homeomorphic to E. So X and E are actually homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Quite interesting indeed. I find amazing how you manage to have so much control over $Spec(A)$ even though its non maximal points can only be "constructed" by using "ultrafilters and similar far-out mysteries" ( *dixit* Mumford, Red Book, page 140 of original notes). Maybe it is time to write a version of Gillman and Gerison's book on rings of continuous from the point of view of Algebraic Geometry, inspired by this kind of techniques...