# Topological fundamental group of spec(R)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Assume that $X = Spec(R)$ with the Zariski topology.

> When is this space path connected? And also we want to know the topological fundamental group of the space $X$. How can we think about these questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, any topological space with a "generic point" (whose closure is the whole space) is contractible.  This covers any integral domains.

Comment: For questions like these, I find it helpful to spend some time getting familiar with the homotopy theory of finite topological spaces. The underlying topological space of the spectrum of a noetherian ring is very similar to a finite topological space (although there are a few minor differences).

Comment: You obviously know it, but I thought it might be useful to list this: The spectrum of $R \times R'$ is the disjoint union of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(R')$. Hence your $X$ is connected if the ring has precisely two idempotents.

Comment: Are you sure this is the question you want to ask? These kinds of spaces are very poorly behaved from the point of view of homotopy theory. There are more interesting ways to apply homotopy-theoretic methods in algebraic geometry.

Comment: [Every finite $T_0$ space is the spectrum of some ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space), so Spec(R) can have the weak homotopy type of any finite CW-complex.  It seems plausible to me that Spec(R) is always weak equivalent to the nerve of its specialization poset (this is true for any finite space, and seems not hard to prove by an induction argument if $R$ is Noetherian).

Comment: Oops, my "plausible" guess is horribly wrong in general.  If $R=C(X)$ is the ring of continuous real-valued functions on a compact Hausdorff space $X$, then every prime is contained in a unique maximal ideal and the space of maximal ideals (which is homeomorphic to $X$) is a deformation-retract of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.  In this case the nerve of the specialization poset has the homotopy type of $X$ with the discrete topology, while $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ has the homotopy of $X$.  See [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/45507/75) for some of the details of this.

Comment: In particular, the example of $C(X)$ suggests that for  completely arbitrary rings, there is no easy way to tell whether the spectrum is path-connected.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that you may be asking the 'wrong' question. The use of paths is inappropriate in this algebraic geometric context, and hence also ideas such as 'path connected' and 'fundmental group(oid)'although there are analogues.

The classical fundamental group classifies covering spaces of $X$, and that is a useful property to generalise. Look at Grothendieck's SGA1 (if you can read French) for the original material on this, but there are lots of more recent  sources 'out there' (including some well written surveys, some done by various Masters students, that are a good read and get you to the point fairly quickly without a lot of generality! One such that I have used is 'M. A. D. Robalo, 2009, Galois Theory towards Dessins d’Enfants,
Master’s thesis, Instituto Superior Technico, Lisboa'. Another very good source is by Dubuc and de la Vega, (and which can be found on the ArXiv as math.CT/0009145.) There are analogues of the fundamental groupoid and of covering spaces and then you can ask if the fundamental groupoid is connected (corresponding to path connectedness in the classical topological case) That fundemantal groupoid is usually thought of as a profinite groupoid, and that may encode the topological information that you are hoping for in the second part of the question. (I should add that it is best to consider general schemes with the étale topology, but to start with that may not be necessary.)

I hope this helps.